# Extend Twig template without blocks

Tags: twig

I have layout template

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And many child templates like this

```
{% extends 'layout/default.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And it's very annoying that every single child template in Twig must include `{% block content %}...{% endblock %}` to be extended by parent block, otherwise there will be error: **A template that extends another one cannot have a body.**

Is there any solution to bind all child template output(that is not located in any block) in some variable, and then use it to paste in parent template? Like this:

Layout

```
<html>
<body>
{{ _context.childOutput }
</body>
</html>
```

Child

```
{% extends 'layout/default.twig' %}
<p>content</p>
```

It will make child templates code more compact and there will be no dependency from parent templates blocks name.

**UPD** Submitted new issue on Twig's GitHub https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2027

Comment: Only "clean" way to achieve this imo would be to create your own parser that extends from the twig's one and move the non-content block into a default block / variable

Comment: Look at the include command: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: include and emeb commands are bad issues because they still adds some trash in child templates, and makes it depended from "parent" template context.

Comment: Is the content of the child template static? Does it contain variables?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 lines you have in each template allows you aswell to redefine many blocks in one template. I can't see how the solution you want can do that.

```
<html>
<head>
{% block meta %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

you can see [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) and [embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) but if you really have only one block in your templates twig is maybe not the solution you need

Comment: I just don't understand what is the problem to make Twig binding all non-block content to some kind of special variable. I think it must be very easy and obvious solution and I'm very surprised that it's not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

While seeing in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2027#issuecomment-215357413) that you define variables in the controller, I had the following idea. I'll assume that the child template only contain static code since you didn't describe this point.

You can modify the function in your controller in order to fetch the content of the child template then pass it to the parent template directly:

```php
function acmeAction()
{
    // …

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeBundle:layout:default.html.twig',
        array(
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'content' => file_get_contents(
                $this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource(
                    '@AcmeBundle/Resources/views/layout/child.html.twig'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

And the parent template:

```
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{{ description }}{% endblock %}" />
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{{ content }}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

This way you won't need to define the parent in the child template.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some variables in the child and display them in the parent:

Layout

```
<html>
<body>
{{ myValue }
</body>
</html>
```

Child

```
{% set myValue %}
    <p>content</p>
{% endset %}
{% include 'layout/default.twig' %}
```

This works because:

> Included templates have access to the variables of the active context.

Source: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

---

> And it's very annoying that every single child template in Twig must include `{% block content %}...{% endblock %}` to be extended by parent block

While it may sound annoying when you only have one variable, you will see the benefits of this approach when you will have to define also the title of the page, the JavaScript code, etc. In this case the use of multiple `{% block … %}` is really useful.

See this example:

Layout

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Child

```
{% extends 'layout/default.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    My title
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>content</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script>…</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see, workaround with `{% set myValue %}` has same amount of code extra lines as in original code that I found annoying. I understand benefits from using multiple blocks for assigning multiple data vars for parent template, but I still don't understand why there is no any special variable that can store non-blocked data.

Comment: @barbushin I'm sorry I don't know how to configure the *parent* of a Twig template without using `include` or `extends`. I'm pretty sure Twig could not guess it.